# Are there more general gauge transformations than simple phase shifts?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Usually, in the context of a $U(1)$ gauge theory, we only consider gauge transformations of the form
\begin{equation} 
    \Psi(x) \to \mathrm{e}^{i\epsilon(x)} \Psi(x) \, .
\end{equation}
Are there more general transformations in our internal space, analogous to how there are more general spacetime symmetries than just Poincare transformations (e.g. conformal transformations)?

Comment: Depends on the theory you're considering!

Comment: @slereah any example would be awesome!

Comment: Weak Isospin ($SU(2)$) or, more generally, the elctroweak force 
($SU(2) \times U(1)$). For Quantum Chromodynamik you use
$SU(3)$, hence the Symmetrygroup of the Standardmodel is given
by $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$,  wich includes $U(1)$ als a special case.
If you, however, only consider an $U(1)$ gauge theory, then there are
only the transformations you already described.

Comment: @Creo Ah yes, of course you're right. Replacing the Poincare group with a larger group is, in some sense, analogous to replacing the internal $U(1)$ group with a larger group. However, a difference, I think is that in the former case we talk about larger symmetries of a given manifold (spacetime) while in the ladder we not only increase the symmetry group from $U(1)$ to e.g. $SU(2)$, but at the same time change the structure of the internal space (the fibers).